# What is the include file for torch::Tensor?

Tags: c++, pytorch, compilation, libtorch

I'm compiling code in C++ which includes <torch/torch.h>. This header file will include the entire libtorch library. The problem is that any source file that includes it takes too long to compile. About 1 minute sometimes. Is there a header file which I can include that only includes the torch::Tensor class.

ex:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <torch/torch.h>    // This header alone takes about 30 seconds to compile!!!
//#include <torch/tensor.h> // Does a header like this exist which only includes the Tensor class?

int main()
{
    torch::Tensor t = torch::zeros({ 4, 5 });

    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code in Visual Studio 2022 with the MSVC compiler. I hoped the code would compile in less time.

Comment: Maybe you could speed up the compilation by using [precompiled header files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files)?

Comment: I'm interested in trying it. Do you know if this works? And can you explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Aten/ATen.h` header file. As per [docs](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/), almost all Python and C++ interfaces in PyTorch are built on top of `ATen`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ATen/ATen.h>

int main() {
  at::Tensor t = at::zeros({4,5});
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

On testing, I found your example took 10 seconds to compile and mine took 5 seconds using CMake on my system (Dell 8GB RAM, Ubuntu OS).

Comment: It worked. #include <torch/torch.h> took 8 extra seconds to compile. #include <ATen/ATen.h> only took 2 extra seconds.